# Why is git clone failing when I build an image from a dockerfile?

Tags: docker

```
FROM ansible/ansible:ubuntu1604

MAINTAINER myname


RUN git clone http://github.com/ansible/ansible.git /tmp/ansible
RUN git clone http://github.com/othertest.git /tmp/othertest
WORKDIR /tmp/ansible
ENV PATH /tmp/ansible/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:bin
ENV PYTHONPATH /tmp/ansible/lib:$PYTHON_PATH
ADD inventory /etc/ansible/hosts
WORKDIR /tmp/
EXPOSE 8888
```

When I build from this dockerfile, I get Cloning into /tmp/ansible and othertest in red text (I assume is an error).  When I then run the container and peruse around, I see that all my steps from the dockerfile built correctly other than the git repositories which are missing.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I'm assuming its a simple mistake.

Building dockerfile:

```
sudo docker build --no-cache -f Dockerfile .
```

Running dockerfile:

```
sudo docker run -I -t de32490234 /bin/bash
```

Comment: Can you post the full Dockerfile (and the parent) please? And how you're running the container to peruse around? Also red text doesn't mean error necessarily (and not in this case).

Comment: I have updated the post.  When I run the container, I can see my ansible hosts that were added, etc.  None of the git repositories appear to be cloned though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer:

Put your files anywhere other than in `/tmp` and things should work fine.

The longer answer:

You're basing your image on the `ansible/ansible:ubuntu1604` image.  If you inspect this image via `docker inspect ansible/ansible:ubuntu1604` or look at the [Dockerfile from which it was built](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/test/utils/docker/ubuntu1604/Dockerfile), you will find that it contains a number of volume mounts.  The relevant line from the Dockerfile is:

```
VOLUME /sys/fs/cgroup /run/lock /run /tmp
```

That means that all of those directories are volume mount points, which means any data placed into them will **not** be committed as part of the image build process.

Looking at your `Dockerfile`, I have two comments unrelated to the above:

- You're explicitly setting the `PATH` environment variable, but you're neglecting to include `/bin`, which will cause all kinds of problems, such as:

  ```
  $ docker run -it --rm bash
  docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH.
  ```
- You're using `WORKDIR` twice, but the first time (`WORKDIR /tmp/ansible`) you're not actually *doing* anything that cares what directory you're in (you're just setting some environment variables and copying a file into `/etc/ansible`).